# what determines the bios you can use

Tags: bios

I have a Compaq sr5710f with a MCP61PM-HM (Iris8) motherboard and loaded a Geforce6100sm-m bios on to it. It works fine and opened up some options, but I want to give my comp am3 socket support. So my question is if I go looking for a bios that will do that for me what do I need to pay attention to. Is it only the chip set which is geforce 6150se nforce 405 or are there more things I should be looking at. If anyone thinks they might know a bios that will help me out that would be good to. I am looking for a retail bios though. I do not want to load any of the experimental ones you can find on the net. Also I would need it to support ddr2 800 ram, and would like to keep am2 support to.

I know my bios is data that is downloaded onto my motherboard, or for lack of a better word a program. I am currently running a bios that is not for my motherboard, so I know it can be done. What I need is what do I need to pay attention to when looking for compatible bios programs, that is not for my motherboard.

Am3 processors are backwards compatible with Am2 sockets, with the right bios update. Some motherboards have issued updates to allow this.  Am3 processors support both ddr2 and ddr3. For prof of this here is a link to a board that does http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813153181

Answer (score 1):

You are at the mercy of the manufacturer of your motherboard. Loading BIOSs not designed and tested for your motherboard is a very risky business, a very minor incompatibility could result in a permanently unusable motherboard. I wouldn't advise trying to swap around BIOSs looking for AM3 support.

Answer (score -1):

AM3 is a different socket than am2. You cannot flash a bios that will support it, as it is a hardware issue. On a separate note, the ddr2 ram will not work on an AM3 socket motherboard anyway.